# German auxiliary verbs taking the infinitive

Tags: word-usage, verb, meaning-in-context

So I happened to come across a couple of sentence examples on Linguee that truly perplexed me, namely:

> „Der Junge wurde bezichtigt, Geld gestohlen zu haben.“
>   „Er war sicher, bei der Prüfung durchgefallen zu sein, aber das Gegenteil traf zu.“

So my question is: why does the auxiliary verb take the infinitive in these sentences, and when is such a grammatical phenomenon ever used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those types of sentences are called **erweiterter Infinitiv mit zu** and are very frequent in German. Your example sentences just so happen to have modal verbs, but that's just a coincidence.

The full infinitive in your first sentence reads

> jemanden bezichtigen etwas **zu tun** (*to accuse someone of doing something*)

This already introduces the *erweiterter Infinitiv mit zu*. If you want to accuse someone of doing something in the past, you may want to use the perfect in German. The perfect is constructed with the auxiliary verb *haben* and the past participle. This leads to

> jemanden bezichtigen etwas getan zu haben

Hence, in full sentence (with a passive construction) this becomes

> Der Junge wurde bezichtig, Geld gestohlen zu haben

The full infinitive of the second sentence is

> sich sicher sein etwas zu sein (*to be sure to be something*)

Now durchfallen uses *sein* to construct the Perfekt. Following the steps above we find

> Er war sich sicher, durchgefallen zu sein.

By not using the Perfekt, we have no need to use the auxiliary verbs, so your sentences would read

> Er wird bezichtigt zu stehlen.
>
> Er ist sich sicher durchzufallen.

Comment: Thanks for the help mate.

Comment: I think _durchgefallen zu sein_ is also a infinitive perfect, in this case of the verb _durchfallen_, _fallen_ forming the present perfect with the auxiliary _sein_.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I said?

Comment: I didn't read the following sentence, sorry. I read 'something' as 'adjective'. Maybe it's misunderstanding. For me, the infinitive of the second sentence ist _ (sich) sicher sein, etwas zu + Infinitv_, and the infinitive can be an infinitive perfect. You can also construct it with an adjective: Er war (sich) sicher, krank zu sein. Here, the infinitive would be _sich sicher sein etwas zu sein_. That's why I misunderstood it.